# Не могу запустить Х-приложение по SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

```
and@and-desktop:~$ ssh -X 192.168.10.34 -l and
and@192.168.10.34's password: 
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-42-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Wed Jan  6 02:18:48 2016 from 192.168.10.33
and@and-EasyNote-DT85:~$
```

Собственно проблемма в том что не могу запустить любое Х-приложение, например наутилус:

```
and@and-EasyNote-DT85:~$ nautilus
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (nautilus:3866): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
(nautilus:3866): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
and@and-EasyNote-DT85:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй `-XY`.

> -Y      Enables trusted X11 forwarding.  Trusted X11 forwardings are not subjected to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.

И ещё. В `sshd_config` надо прописать строку `X11Forwarding yes`.

Comment: Действительно, атрибут -Y помог, но почему раньше без него работало, а сейчас нет. Почему появился этот варнинг: Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding. ?   У меня после манипуляций с SSH перестали запускаться иксы из страницы авторизации, пришлось удалить: rm .Xauthority .ICEauthority. Может это как то повлияло?     В sshd_config  было прописано  X11Forwarding yes.

Comment: XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth - добавь ещё эту строку в конфиг. Должно помочь.

Comment: Да, раз помогло - отметь пожалуйста ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 0):

На удаленной машине перед запуском nautilus выполните

```
export DISPLAY=192.168.10.34:0
```